# Find the $\gcd(6, 14, 21)$ and express it in the form $6r+14s+21t$ for $r,s, t\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Find the $\gcd(6, 14, 21)$ and express it in the form $6r+14s+21t$ for $r,s,t\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I'm trying to learn some number theory, which starts with this gcd thing.  But I ran into a problem: I know how to find the gcd of two numbers $x,y$ and express it as a $ax+by=gcd(x,y)$ (legitally using the Euclidean), but I'm not sure how to find, in this case, $6,14,21$ in the form of $6r+14s+21t$.

I can find the gcd using common sense, which is $1$, but how do I express it in the form provided there.

I can find it using brute force but there should be a more systematically way I believe.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $\gcd(x, y, z) = \gcd(\gcd(x, y), z)$.

If you need more than this, feel free to comment and I can add more. :)

Comment: So gcd(x,y,z) is also equal to gcd(x,gcd(y,z)) or gcd(y,gcd(x,z)? Can you show me how that is possible?

Comment: Yup! Think about it this way - if any one of the three holds, any of the others hold by symmetry (i.e., by interchanging what we call $x, y, z$). As for how to prove it, try writing out what each side is - that should give you an informal idea. For formal proof, there are many options - one could be to show that the RHS divides the LHS and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the help man!  You rock!

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

$$(6,14,21)=((6,14),21)=(2,21)=1$$

As $7-3.2=1\iff 14(1)+6(-2)=2$

Now, as $21+2(-10)=1\implies 21+\{\underbrace{14(1)+6(-2)}\}(-10)=1\implies 21(1)+14(-10)+6(20)=1$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First find the integers $r,s$ such that $\gcd(r,s)=6r+14s$.